# type object 'Review' has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, django, database, web, server

```
class Review(models.Model):
def __str__(self):
    return self.reviewText
item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
reviewText = models.CharField(max_length=50)
votes = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

This is my models.py file. And Bellow is my views.py file.

```
def order(request, item_id):
item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=item_id)
if request.method == "POST":
    username = None
    username = request.user.username
    userInfo = username + '/' + request.POST["nameNum"]
    userAddr = request.POST["address"]
    new_order = Review.object.create(
        reviewText = userInfo,
        votes = userAddr
    )
    return HttpResponse("<script>alert('" + userInfo + '/ ' + userAddr + "');</script> 등록 완료")
return render(request, 'order.html', {'item': item})
```

And when I run this part on my local server, **type object 'Review' has no attribute 'object'** << this error occurs. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Review.objects.create

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
new_order = Review.object.create(
        reviewText = userInfo,
        votes = userAddr
    )
enter code here
```

Looks like a syntax error (you seem to forget typing ***s*** (plural of object):

it's Review.object**s** not object

Answer (score 1):

It is `Review.objects` not `Review.object`